# Application Specific Password issues

Tags: passwords, google-authentication

I'd like to implement 2-factor authentication for a google account but also need to connect to Google services in various scripts.

Does each script require its own ASP? How does Google define what an "application" is?

If two people run the same script from different machines will they each need a unique ASP?

Answer (score 0):

You should never embed passwords in code.

Instead, you should use OAuth to get a token that grants permission to perform the appropriate actions.
This is the preferred way to use services from code, and should be supported by all Google APIs.

---

The answer to your question is whatever you want.
The point of having multiple app-specific passwords is to allow you to revoke one of them without affecting others (in case one device gets stolen).
You can use each password as many times as you want.

Comment: I consider my hosting environment to be secure and store passwords as environmental variables there.

Comment: It's still better to use OAuth.